# two same attributes in POST

Tags: post, yii, filefield

I need to upload file with `Yii`. In view I have row: 
`<?php echo CHtml::activefileField($qualificationModel, 'picture'); ?>`, where

> $qualificationModel = new SkillsMapping;

Part of controller:

```
 $skillsModel = SkillsMapping::model();
 $skillsModel->attributes=$_POST['SkillsMapping'];
 $skillsModel->picture=CUploadedFile::getInstance($skillsModel,'picture');
 echo  var_dump($_FILES);
 if($skillsModel->validate())
 {
    if($skillsModel->save())
    {
       $skillsModel->picture->saveAs('images/qual-pics');
       $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->user_id));
    }
 }
```

When i chose photo and clicked button i have a error `Picture cannot be blank.`
After checking POST request i founded strange thing - request have two attributes - `SkillsMapping[picture]=` and `SkillsMapping[picture]=Lighthouse.jpg`. If commented echo in top of this post, both attributes disappear. How to remove empty `SkillsMapping[picture]` and why it's going? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to remove the empty hidden field because it's there to help you, not hurt you (Yii itself automatically puts it there; see the [relevant part of the source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1432)).

The hidden field is there so that `$_POST` is populated with an empty value when no file has been selected to upload. If a file *has* been selected the file input control will provide its own POST value that overwrites the empty "guard value".

Comment: Okay, but why my model doesn't validate?

Comment: @f0rtis: I have no idea. Use `$skillsModel->getErrors()` to find out.